# Give the equations that are a tangent to the parabola $y = x^2 + 5x + 6$ and pass through $(1,1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have been given the question:

> Give the equations that are a tangent to the parabola: $y = x^2 + 5x + 6$ and pass through the point $(1,1)$

I have tried two different methods for solving this. The first I don't know why am I incorrect (I would appreciate if someone would explain to me where I went wrong).

First Attempt:

$y = x^2 + 5x + 6$

Use $y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$ to create lines that go through $(1,1)$

$y - 1 = m(x - 1)$

$y = mx + 1 - m$

Find when these lines intersect with the parabola:

$x^2 + 5x + 6 = mx + 1 - m$

$x^2 + x(5 - m) + (5 + m) = 0$

Find for what values of M these lines only intersect once using $b^2 - 4ac = 0$

$(5-m)^2 - 4(5+m) = 0 = m^2 - 14m + 5$

$(m - 7)^2 - 49= -5$

$m = \pm \sqrt{44} + 7$

Giving the equations:

$$
y = (\sqrt{44} + 7)x - \sqrt{44} + 1
$$
$$
y = (-\sqrt{44} + 7)x + \sqrt{44} + 1
$$

With the second attempt I am lost as to what that last equation is representing so I just got confused.

second:
$ y = x^2 + 5x + 6 $

$ y' = 2x + 5 $

All the lines that have the same gradient as a the parabola and pass through $(1,1)$
$ y - 1 = (2x + 5)(x - 1) $

$y = 2x^2 + 3x - 4$

Find when these intersect the parabola:

$x^2 + 5x + 6 = 2x^2 + 3x - 4$

which gave:

$x = \pm3 + 1$

From here I got lost and didn't know what was going on.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain why my first method is wrong, tell me if either of the methods are even on track to solving the issue and give an answer to the problem.

Thanks
-Kingpulse

---

**Solution for method one**

The first method was actually correct apart from at the very end.
The mistake was the incorrect substitution into $-m$, I was substituting $-\sqrt{44}$ into $-m$ not $-(\sqrt{44}+7)$.

Proof that it is a tangent:

Parabola : $y = x^2 + 5x + 6$

Find intersections of lines

$x^2 + 5x + 6 = (\sqrt{44} + 7)x - (\sqrt{44} + 7) + 1$

$x^2 + x(-2-\sqrt{44}) + (12 + \sqrt{44}) = 0$

$b^2 - 4ac = 0$ if it is a tangent (only one root)

$(-2-\sqrt{44})^2 - 4(12+\sqrt{44})$

$4+4\sqrt{44} + 44 - 48 -4\sqrt{44} = 0$

It is a tangent.

The equations are:

$$ y = (\sqrt{44} + 7)x - (\sqrt{44} + 7) + 1$$

and

$$ y = (-\sqrt{44} + 7)x - (-\sqrt{44} + 7) + 1$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For the second use parametric form $(t,t^2+5t+6)$

$$\dfrac{y-(t^2+5t+6)}{x-t}=(2x+5)_{(\text{ at }x=t)}$$

Now set $x=1,y=1$ to find the two values of $t$ to b $$1\pm\sqrt{11}$$

$$m=(2x+5)_{(\text{ at }x=t)}=2t+5=?$$

Comment: @KingPulse, Please find the adjusted version.

Comment: I have never used parametric forms for solving things like this before. Ill give it a go though.

Comment: I am a bit confused by what is going on in your hint, could you give me a little bit more?

Comment: @KingPulse, I wanted to show that : If you adjust your second method with parameters like that of mine, the result will converge with that of the first one.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand what you mean. Ill give that a go in the morning and show you how I go.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is OK. For the second method, you have to consider a point $x_0,y_0)$  on the parabola, write the equation of the tangent to  the parabola at that point:
$$y=(2x_0+5)(x-x_0)+x_0^2+5x_0+6=(2x_0+5)x-x_0^2+6$$
and write this tangent passes though the point $(1,1)$:
$$1=2x_0+5-x_0^2+6\iff x_0^2-2x_0-10=0.$$
The reduced discriminant is $\Delta'=11$, hence 
$$x_0=1\pm\sqrt 11.$$

Comment: I will try that method, however the equations from the first method are wrong. They intersect the parabola twice.

Comment: There's an error in the final equations of the tangent lines: you should find $y=(\sqrt{44}+7)x-\sqrt{44}\color{red}-1$ and $y=(-\sqrt{44}+7)x+\sqrt{44}\color{red}-1$.

Comment: Those both intersect twice again. Sorry.
I do however think I have found the problem. It is $y = mx - m + 1$ and I am only substituting in $\sqrt{44}$ for the $-m$ not $(\sqrt{44} + 7)$. I have graphed the following equation: $y = (\sqrt{44} + 7)x - (\sqrt{44} + 7) + 1$ with the parabola and it looks like it is the correct equation when graphed. How would I prove that it is a tangent to the curve to see if its correct?

Comment: Form the equation for the abscissae of the intersection points with the parabola, and check if its (reduced)  discriminant is $0$. Finally, the equations of the tangents have $-6\pm2\sqrt{11}$ as a constant term.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help. The problem is now solved through using the first method c:

Answer (score 2):

Your computation for $b^2-4ac$ should have $5+m$ in the second term.

Also in the second method your notation is confusing you and you have $y=2x^2+3x-4$ as the equation of a straight line, which is wrong. You need to deal with the point you know, which is $(x_0,y_0)$ on the parabola, where the gradient is $2x_0+5$, work out the equation of the tangent line, and then, when you have it, find the condition that it passes through $(1,1)$.

Comment: Changed to (5+m). Thanks.